# having trouble configuring Django on the atom editor for a Mac computer

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am trying to set up Django the newest version with python 3 and I keep getting errors about the path way. this is what it is saying and the following is my configurations. Note: I have uninstalled and installed and even wrote it to the exact way their website directs with no luck. it just changes around the error.

terminal:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/patrickjobe/Desktop/wordcount/wordcount/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('index/', views.index),
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

urls.py page configs

```
rom django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings.py page

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py page

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is unrelated to your django installation, and has nothing to do with filesystem paths.

You simply need `from django.urls import path` before using the `path` function.